# How to apply @ConstructorProperties to a case class in Scala?

Tags: scala, xml-serialization

I would like to add serialization support with XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder to a case class in Scala. Here's my attempt:

```
@ConstructorProperties(Array("sequenceNumber", "nanosecondsTotal", "bytesTotal", "timeMillis"))
final case class IoStatistics(
  @BeanProperty sequenceNumber: Long,
  @BeanProperty nanosecondsTotal: Long,
  @BeanProperty bytesTotal: Long,
  @BeanProperty timeMillis: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
) {
  ...
}
```

I can verify with javap that the generated class indeed has the public four-argument constructor and the appropriate bean getters for the properties. However, when trying to serialize an instance with `XMLEncoder` I get the following console output:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: net.java.truevfs.ext.jmx.model.IoStatistics
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: XMLEncoder: discarding statement XMLEncoder.writeObject(IoStatistics);
Continuing ...
```

and the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_06" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
</java>
```

It seems the annotation is not applied to the constructor. How can I verify and fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about XML serialization, but maybe you should apply the `ConstructorProperties` annotation to the constructor instead of to the class?

```
case class Foo @ConstructorProperties(Array("sequenceNumber", "nanosecondsTotal", "bytesTotal", "timeMillis"))(
  @BeanProperty sequenceNumber: Long,
  @BeanProperty nanosecondsTotal: Long,
  @BeanProperty bytesTotal: Long,
  @BeanProperty timeMillis: Long = System.currentTimeMillis
) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Right - I just found out myself, too. Actually, I find this syntax a bit odd, especially the fact that the opening brace needs to be on the same line as the annotation - otherwise the compiler refuses it. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: The syntax is consistent with that for the visibility modifiers though. For example: `class Foo private() {}`

Comment: Yes, but it looks odd and even more with long annotations. Anyway, that's just a matter of style. Thanks again!